# Problem solving strategies in differential topology

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

I was wondering if there is a bag of tricks somewhere for differential topology and smooth manifold problems just like there is for analysis by prof. Tao

http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/245a-problem-solving-strategies/.

What are some strategies/arguments you find useful? Please share below.

Here are some I find useful:

1)**Clopen argument**

To show a property is global in a connected space X, consider $S=\{x:P(x)$ is true $\}$ and prove it's clopen. Thus, by uniqueness $S=X$.

2)**Extending to show continuity/smoothness**

Extend the map in a larger space and show is continuous/smooth. Then by restricting to submanifolds, continuity/smoothness is preserved.

3)**Baire category theorem**

Every countable union of nowhere dense sets has empty interior. This is true for locally compact spaces and thus manifolds.

PS.
If this not the right tag (ie. if it a community post) feel free to move it.